# Multitenant app and hangfire jobs, new job per tenant or one job iteration?

Tags: azure, hangfire

I have a multi tenant app which requires 3 hangfire jobs.

1. First job fetches data from one service and store it in database.
2. Second job picks up the payloads from first job and process them to convert them
3. Third job picks up processed payloads and post them to another service.

Each job is being enqueued every 5th minute (using recurring jobs). Now with single tenant, this method was fairly easy to implement. However, now as I am moving to multi-tenant app. I want to know what would be the ideal way to achieve it.

1. 3 new jobs each tenant
2. 3 app level jobs. Each job will iterate through tenant's payload and process them accordingly?

I am quite new to Hangfire so wondering if any expert would like to jump in and provide me with the suggestions and best practices tips.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue.  Have you come to any resolution?